# simple_form Collection Radio Button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I have a form where these radio buttons are duplicated between two forms:

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :type, [['cardio', 'Cardio'], ['weights', 'Weights']], :first, :last, :item_wrapper_class => 'radio-inline'
```

Is there a way to add a class to the radio button, so these can be easily distinguished via jquery and how would you do it using haml, as if I append on the ID, the value on the database is changed?

Comment: I've never used `simple-form`, but I would think it does it for you. Look at the rendered html when you load the page and see what it outputs. Of course, you can just not use `simple-form` and use [the regular radio_button](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An collection radio buttons like:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last
end
```

result

```
<input id="user_options_true" name="user[options]" type="radio" value="true" />
<label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_options_true">Yes</label>
<input id="user_options_false" name="user[options]" type="radio" value="false" />
<label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_options_false">No</label>
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-radio-buttons

So you should try to override the CSS class 'collection_radio_buttons' and the 'ID' generated in the input.